# How do I efficiently partition a set of item pairs with varying quantities

Tags: algorithms

Apologies in advance if my terminology is off.  I'm not a mathematician (just a programmer).

I have a set of item pairs (a shopping cart) where each item has a quantity

```
1x item A
1x item B
2x item C
1x item D
1x item E
```

I have a discount code that requires a minimum quantity of items in the cart in order to be applicable.  The goal is to maximize the discount.

If the minimum was 3 items, there would be two candidates for this cart:

```
(A, B, C, D, E) = $50 discount
(A, B, C)  (C, D, E) = $60 discount (since we can use 'C' twice)
```

Rather than brute-forcing it, is there an algorithm used for calculating the optimal way to partition sets of pairs like these?  Or even a hint of a branch of maths I should be looking into?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: It's not clear how this is being assigned, is it $10 per unique item in a subgroup?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $10 per item in a subgroup.  And an item will only appear once per subgroup.

Comment: What do you mean by pairs?  I only see two of one thing, that is C.  You have to specify the rules.  It appears that you cannot apply the discount to two of the same item in a group.  You can simply make groups of $3$, starting with the most common items.  If you have one or two left over, add them into some group.  That gets every item into a group as long as there are at least $3$ and not to many of one kind.  What is wrong with that?  That will help clarify the question.